# Solve CalendarExtender dose not display properly

Tags: css, calendarextender

If  you have problem in displaying `CalendarExtender` when it appears like    this:

[image]

You could solve problem by right-clicking on your project and then selecting Manage NuGet packages. Then follow this picture bellow

[image]

Comment: We need code! How can anyone help you if you don't show your code?

Comment: problem already solved. see the solution down

Comment: Yet I ask you to still [edit] your question and put in your non-working code. This site is not just for you to get answers, it is also for others to find solutions to similar problems of their own. The same goes for your solution. The text in the screen shot is hardly readable. And *why* is what you described a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve problem by right-clicking on your project and then selecting `Manage NuGet packages`.    Then follow this picture bellow
[image]

Follow this picture below.